# How To Use UUIDs With Hibernate And MySQL(JPA /Hibernate / MySQL)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, annotations, uuid

I'm encountering the following exception with hibernate:

> java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xD4BRh\xF09...' for
> column 'id' at row 1

I have a Java/JPA/Hibernate/MySQL based app. I want to use UUIDs for object identity.
This is when trying to save a uuid in a mysql database. The database is configured to use utf8mb4 (and utf8mb4_general_ci collation). MySQL version 8.0.22

With the following column definition

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
@GenericGenerator(
        name = "UUID",
        strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
)
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
private UUID id;
```

**Is there something I'm missing? Thank you!**

Comment: What database type do you use for the id column? What hibernate dialect do you use? What hibernate version do you use?

Comment: my id coloum type is `binary(16)`  and i use hibernate dialect MySQL57Dialect, which i currently use hibernate version is 5.4.23